# Forwarding does not work over http

Tags: domain-forwarding, google-domains

This is my configuration for my domain.

[image: Google domains forwarding configuration]

This is the results when i use curl. It seems like the https request is correct, but the http request crashes the DNS server (squid is DNS server software).

[image: curl request results]

Has anyone else encountered this error? I'd like to get this fix as this is causes people who enter the url without http or www to occasionally not be able to access the website. I talked to support and they said my DNS was configured correctly.

Comment: Squid is not a DNS server.  Squid is a caching proxy server.  http://www.squid-cache.org/

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Google's domain forwarding services.  Have you tried to contact them for technical support?

Comment: Yeah I have, they said that "there are no bugs on google domains", which seemed like a stretch. I might try again today